# How to configure PhpStorm Remote Xdebug path mapping

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have setup and docker machine that runs my application. In this docker machine xdebug is enabled with these xdebug.ini settings.

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=10.5.0.1
```

My local machines IP is 10.5.0.1

When I try to run my application on command line, it connects back to PhpStorm debugger. But because of there is no path mapping it stops at the first line of the script, break points doesn't work. Break point cursor is not visible, I can't track the code by `F8` key.

Also, it must show some kind of path mapping error Debugger->Variables windows, but it doesn't show any error.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

settings > languages and frameworks > php > servers
Add your server, and add your path mapping! 
An example would be C:\Sites\mysite mapped to remote /var/www/mysite or similar

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work. It doesn't work when I call it from command line, but works good if I call the same file via browser on remote host.

Comment: In the command line, using the latest xdebug, you can set the envirionment var as you run a command, e.g. `XDEBUG_MODE=debug ./some/command`, that should work for you

Answer (score 6):

I could fix this problem, PhpStorm can not handle if `serverName` is not configured.

#### What to do:

1. Setup environment variables:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=web_server_cli"
```

2. Setup path mapping for that servername:

Go to `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP` and create a server with a hostname `web_server_cli`

Comment: Doing what @Benjamin is suggesting is the easiest way, especially if you invoke such scripts yourself from within the IDE. But, if you wish to debug some random script (e.g. invoked by cron; launched manually via remote console etc) then this is the way to go.

Comment: If I could give you 50 rep for this I would. The nightmare I've had trying to get this working. I still don't know why it couldn't resolve the paths without this but at least it's sorted now.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set up a "server" configuration in "Settings > Languages and Frameworks > PHP > Servers" which maps the paths as seen on the server to the paths in your project.

Normally, you would enter a URL into "Host" and set "Port" to the HTTP port, e.g. 80 or 443. For CLI scripts, the info to put in here will be based on your connection to the server where the CLI script runs. For instance, if you SSH to 192.168.42.42 on the standard SSH port (22), you would enter "Host: 192.168.42.42", and "Port: 22".

To find out what details you need to set up, go into "Settings > Languages and Frameworks > PHP > Debug", enable "Force break at the first line when no path mapping specified", and make sure "Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations" is *not* ticked. Then click "Listen for debug connections" in the toolbar, and run your script; a dialog box should pop up showing the "Server name:" and "Server port:" it is trying to match, as well as confirming the remote file path. Click "Ignore" on that dialog, set up the server mapping, and try again, and you should get a proper debug session.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment to @delboy1978uk's answer, it looks like you want to debug a PHP script you are running from the command line. To effectively debug this, then rather than debugging this via a 'PHP Remote Application' run configuration (which PHPStorm will assume you are running via a browser) you will need to:

1. Create a 'PHP Script' run configuration with the required arguments to run your CLI application.
2. Set up a Remote CLI PHP interpreter (I run via IDEA, so for me this is located in `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > CLI Interpreter`, YMMV) and supply it with the SSH credentials used to connect to your vagrant box
3. Initiate your Script via the run configuration in Debug Mode.

If all is set up correctly, your CLI script will start and use the breakpoints correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was an error:

"Remote file path '/var/www/my_project/vendor/magento/framework/Profiler/Driver/Standard.php' is not mapped to any file path in project"

"Click to set up path mappings" https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Nr3.png

Click "Click to set up path mappings"

A pop-up window will open https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdsOV.png

Select a path from the list https://i.stack.imgur.com/85gXr.png

Click OK https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPe1v.png