# Xdebug not stopping at breakpoints in PhpStorm when using Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-sail

I am facing an issue with Xdebug in PhpStorm while debugging a PHP Laravel project within a Docker container. It's breaking on the first line but not stopping at my breakpoints. Here are the details of my setup:

I'm using WSL, Docker and Laravel Sail to run my PHP application in PhpStorm.
I have configured Xdebug in my Docker container, and it appears to be working since it breaks at the first line of code.
However, when I set breakpoints in my PHP code and start debugging, PhpStorm doesn't stop at these breakpoints. I suspect it's a path mapping issue. I already tried many solutions but i cannot fix this path mapping issue.

Environment Variable

```
FORWARD_DB_PORT=33064
APP_PORT=8014
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
```

Screenshots of my PhpStorm Settings:

[image: xdebug config]

[image: path mappings]

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Can anyone help me identify what might be causing this problem? Is there something I'm missing in terms of path mappings or configuration?

I've already tried the following:

[Configure Xdebug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html)
[Sail Laravel 8.0 Debugging with XDebug & PHPStorm](https://medium.com/codex/laravel-8-0-sail-xdebug-phpstorm-5cc900e96da4)
[configure PhpStorm Remote Xdebug path mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467655/how-to-configure-phpstorm-remote-xdebug-path-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the absolute path. click on `src` (on the `Absolute path on the server` field), you have to put the path that the container is using, I cannot remember Sail what is using, but go inside the container and do `pwd`, that path must be entered in that column I mentioned you

Comment: Hi,
I already tried with (absolute path on the server) which is (/var/www/html) in my case but it is still not working.

Comment: You can turn on an option saying something like `Break on first line of code` or similar on the menu on the first image. When that happens, an automatic breakpoint should "appear" on whatever file is accessed. You will see available variables and other stuff on the `Debug` tab that showed up, see the variables tab, you will see if it is incorrectly mapping (you will see an error). So report that back to us please.

Comment: What you may be missing is an option on the docker compose xdebug's config: `serverName=whatever`, so you then name your second image as `whatever` instead of `0.0.0.0`. But first report on the previous comment. I never used Sail with xdebug, so I am not sure if you need to add that or not (on normal configs I have to add it all the time)